# Attribution de *Chacun se bat pour ce qui lui manque*

Tags: expressions, expressions-idiomatiques, histoire

Ceci est lié à la question récente chez History SE: [*Did the famous French privateer Surcouf really drop that epic zinger on an anonymous British officer?*](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/72467/49363)

[L'article sur Robert Surcouf](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Surcouf) de Wikipédia en français dit :

> Quand un officier britannique a contesté la noblesse de Surcouf avec ces mots : « Vous, Français, vous vous battez pour l'argent. Tandis que nous, Anglais, nous nous battons pour l'honneur ! » Surcouf a répliqué : ***« Chacun se bat pour ce qui lui manque. »***

Un source possible pour cette citation est [*Voyages, aventures et combats* par Ambroise Louis Garneray](https://citations.institut-iliade.com/les-anglais-disait-il-ne-combattaient-que-pour-lhonneur-et-pour-la-gloire/).

Wikipédia attribue cette expression à Surcouf et la plupart des résultats chez Google vont dans le même sens. À quelques endroits une phrase semblable est attribuée à [René Duguay-Trouin](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ren%C3%A9_Duguay-Trouin) dans la forme un peu différente :

> Les Français se battent pour le butin, tandis que les Allemands ne veulent que la gloire. — Oui Monsieur le Comte, ***nous nous battons chacun afin de conquérir ce qui nous manque.***

(Notons que ce dernier a vécu un siècle avant Surcouf.)

La question est où cette expression paraît-elle pour la première fois et qui en est l'auteur.

Comment: Peut-être que la question pourrait aussi être posée sur le Skeptics SE ?

Comment: voir aussi :https://www.histoire-en-citations.fr/citations/les-francais-se-battent-pour-le-butin-tandis

Comment: @None: In the quoted book "René DUGUAY-TROUIN (1673-1736), Mémoires (posthume, 1740)", there is no trace of this saying.